# Exception when starting an activity Galaxy S5

Tags: android, galaxy, android-file, android-permissions

We are testing our app, and I am not able to repro this (as title mentioned) on my Galaxy S3 nor Nexus 7. The issue happens only on my Galaxy 5S (KOT49H.G900VVRU1ANE9)

SA = 2.0.0060
V = 19
HWD = 1920X1080 3.0
dpi = 480
SIZE = 2
LOCALE = en_US
CSC = VZW
MCC = 311
MNC = 480
T = user
DEVICE = kltevzw
P = kltevzw
I = KOT49H
M = SM-G900V
OKLEFT = false
DIS KOT49H.G900VVRU1ANE9
PSS = 5.219788042639568

However, there is no problem on another Galaxy 5S (KOT49H.G900VVRUANCG).

I know this is a device specific issue, maybe it also depends on environment setup on the device, but I can't get it hand (it's on abroad).

Could anyone give me some lights, thoughts?

The LogCat snippet is attached below:

```
09-04 12:06:41.341  9624  9624 E GDSf1   :  Stack:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.good.salesforce1.alpha/com.good.salesforce1.alpha.LaunchActivity}:
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173) at
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) at
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579) at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) at
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) at
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
    java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) at
    java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946) at
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) ... 11 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) at     libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method) at
    libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110) at
    java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939) ... 12 more
```

Comment: sounds more like a permission related issue. But if it is working on other devices, may be a problem with the SD card on your S5?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,there is no SDCard on this device.

Comment: Sorry too late to answer this question.In my project,for security thinking,I make the directory /data/data/mypackagename/ read-only.See the log,under some Samsung ROM,it will access the internal data directory of the app before it start an activity while the directory is set read-only,that's make the problem.The workaround is:delay to set the folder read-only to Activity:onCreate().It works well in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permissions problem, possibly SELinux related. Samsung is known for permissions problems, so it might well be the firmware's fault.

Troubleshooting steps (assuming that your device is rooted):

Can you try (in a shell):
su
/system/bin/restorecon -R /data/data/com.good.salesforce1.alpha

If the problem persists, please post the results of:
busybox ls -aln /data/data/com.good.salesforce1.alpha

Then try:
busybox chmod 751 /data/data/com.good.salesforce1.alpha

If nothing helped, try:
busybox chmod -R 777 /data/data/com.good.salesforce1.alpha

Caution: the last command may cause security issues (all apps could access your app's data). Be sure to un-install and reinstall your app afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your information,it inspires me to the RC.